# AWS IoT-Core - Policy cannot be created - size exceeds hard limit (2048) - How to solve this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, x509certificate, aws-iot-core

I am creating certificates for `IoT devices` inside `AWS IoT-Core` in an automated process.
Each certificate is allowed to `publish` and `subscribe` only to specific topics, defined in the policy.

If I use only 3 to 5 topics it works, the certificate is created and allowed to publish or subscribe to these topics.

If I try to create a list of 10 or more topics it doesn't work. In fact it is trowing this error with 10 topics. Because the JSON policy becomes bigger than `2048`.

This is the error

```
Error
The action failed because the input is not valid. Policy cannot be created - size exceeds hard limit (2048)
```

And this is the policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Connect"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Subscribe"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxxx:topicfilter/*/topic1/level2",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxxx:topicfilter/*/topic2/level2",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxxx:topicfilter/*/topic3/level2",
        ... 20 more topics
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Publish"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxxx:topic/*/topic1/level2",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxxx:topic/*/topic2/level2",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxxx:topic/*/topic3/level2",
        ... 20 more topics
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So in my opinion we could have 2 possible solutions here to solve my issue:

1. Increase the limit of the policy
2. Change the strategy on how to limit devices to publish or subscribe to specific channels

Any idea in how to solve this issue with the previous strategy or other one?

---

This is the same question in [AWS dev-forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=970580&#970580) with no answer.

Comment: Not sure about your case, however, If you could use IoT policy variable and/or wild card then policy size may be reduced.

Comment: @Tejaskumar I think the wild card can solve this issue now but it can't scale. If I would have 40 topics for example. Also I am investigate split topics between many policies and attach many policies to the certificate. But that would overengeneer the system.